# Disable (click) function based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

here the enableAddLink function looks like this in the typescript

```js
enableAddLink() {
    this.storyboard.network.addNodeMode = false;
    this.addNodeMode = false;
    this.addLinkMode = !this.addLinkMode;
    this.storyboard.network.addLinkMode = this.addLinkMode;
  }
```

The `links` should get created only when `nodes` exist else I want it to be disabled.

Comment: Your code doesn't indicate how we can know whether a node exists. Is there a `node` object or a `nodes` array we should  have access to? We may need to see more code, possibly including the relevant HTML. Also, please show us what you have already tried, and indicate how the results differed from what you wanted.

Comment: Please add some details to let us understand the whole context of problem, otherwise we won't be able to help you :)

Comment: We can not help from a little info like that. Please provide more code!

Comment: sorry guys, newbie here. But was eventually able to fix my problem using an if condition with the node object. @Cat correct on this one , Umar Farooq and Don, thanks for suggestions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what you mean by `nodes`. But if you want to disable an event handler binding based on a single variable, you could do so by using the ternary operator. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent {
  nodes: boolean = true;

  onClick(event) {
    console.log('button clicked');
  }
}
```

Template

```
<button (click)="nodes ? onClick(event) : ''">Click me</button>
```

Comment: What you're saying is correct, had to use the ternary operator and set a condition accordingly. Thanks !